# Dynamically Casting Objects

Tags: c#, .net, object, properties, dynamic-cast

Hello everyone I am trying to cast two objects to, both, a specific type based on property reflection information. I want to do this dynamically so I don't need a bunch of switch cases and such for each type that the two objects can be in this class. Overall they will mostly be int or float. At the moment I currently tried using 'var' and 'object' keywords to hold the incoming adjustment value and the properties original value.

```
// .. snip

/* Get property information. */
PropertyInfo propInfo = classObj.GetType().GetProperty("property-name");
if (propInfo == null)
    continue;

/* Prepare object values. */
object orgVal = propInfo.GetValue( classObj, null );
object adjVal = Convert.ChangeType( strAdjust, propInfo.GetType(), new CultureInfo("en-us"));

// .. math on objects here
// ex. orgVal += adjVal;

// .. snip
```

The incoming adjustment value is in a string but is either in 'int' or 'float' format so it will be easily converted. All of this works fine, it's just the casting to be allowed to adjust the original value with the new adjustment value that is the issue.

I know with .NET 4.0 there is the 'dynamic' keyword that would be able to accomplish something like this, but currently I am stuck using 3.5.

Both objects will use the type from the property information propInfo.GetType().

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure I'm probably overlooking a basic thing here to get this accomplished. Thanks in advance.

-CK

Edit:

Forgot to mention, sorry, this is being developed on a Zune HD, so the framework I have access to is fairly limited to what can/can't be used.

Comment: Sorry CK, I really can't see from the question what you're trying to accomplish.  Why are you trying to do this, and what error are you seeing when you run your code?

Comment: The end result is dynamically handle math on two objects that can be of various types during runtime based on the property information returned from reflection. For example:

<pre><code>
int n1 = 12;
int n2 = 34;
int n3 = n1 + n2;
</code></pre>

You can't do this to 'object' variables, so I am looking for a way to cast them without having to have the casts hard coded, or having to use blocks of checks and statically coded conversions for each type.

Comment: I'm not certain this is possible to be honest. Without doing switch-case of if-elseif I have no idea how this can be done (even with the dynamic). Typecasting is handled compiletime (if I'm not mistaken, which of cause might be the case), and getting that to be done dynamically I don't think is possible. However, if it's just numbers coming in, why not just cast all to double/float?

Comment: The idea of doing all casts as float/double was in mind, but if I planned to extend further I'd have to add more code to handle other types which is why I wanted to see if a more dynamic approach would be possible first.

Answer (score 2):

C# 3.5 has a class called TypeConverter
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx

These provide a mechanism of converting from one type to another based on type information.

```
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter GetConverter(System.Type type)
```

is used to get the converter and

```
public object TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(object value)
```

does the conversion. There are built in converters for basic types like int and float, and it is possible to write custom converters for your own types.

Microsoft has a guide to writing them here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Spike, I left out some info I completely overlooked when I typed up the question. I cannot use this class because this is being developed for the Zune HD. I don't have access to TypeConverter at all, the class is empty, and TypeDescritpor is missing a lot as well.

MSDN says it works on Zune, but apparently not on Zune HD. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you can do this that I can think of. You can use reflection to get the "op_Addition" method (which is basically "operator +"). But the way I'd do it is via Lambdas:

```
var orgValueParam = Expression.Parameter(propInfo.PropertyType, "lhs");
var adjValueParam = Expression.Parameter(propInfo.PropertyType, "rhs");

var expr = Expression.Add(orgValueParam, adjValueParam);
var func = Expression.Lambda(expr, orgValueParam, adjValueParam).Compile();
var result = func(orgValue, adjValue);
```

Note: I haven't actually tested this, so I don't know whether it'll work for sure, but that's where I'd start...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion as well codeka. As stated above I forgot to mention this is for Zune HD developement. I also cannot access the Linq Expression class either on this device, the class does not exist in the Zune HD framework.